# Group by within a groupby then averaging

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a dataframe (I'll just use a simple example) that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'Col1':[3,4,2,6,5,7,3,4,9,7,1,3],
      'Col2':['B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A','C','C','C','C',], 
      'Col3':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Which gives a dataframe like so:

```
    Col1 Col2  Col3
0      3    B     1
1      4    B     1
2      2    B     2
3      6    B     2
4      5    A     1
5      7    A     1
6      3    A     2
7      4    A     2
8      9    C     1
9      7    C     1
10     1    C     2
11     3    C     2
```

What I want to do is several steps:

1) For each unique value in Col2, and for each unique value in Col3, average Col1. So a desired output would be:

```
         Avg   Col2  Col3
    1    3.5    B     1
    2      4    B     2
    3      6    A     1
    4    3.5    A     2
    5      8    C     1
    6      2    C     2
```

2) Now, for each unique value in Col3, I want the highest average and the corresponding value in Col2. So

```
     Best Avg   Col2  Col3
    1      8    C     1
    2      4    B     2
```

My attempt has been using `df.groupby(['Col3','Col2'], as_index = False).agg({'Col1':'mean'}).groupby(['Col3']).agg({'Col1':'max'})`

This gives me the highest average for each Col3 value, but not the corresponding Col2 label. Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you first `groupby` do `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
g1=df.groupby(['Col3','Col2'], as_index = False).agg({'Col1':'mean'})
g1.sort_values('Col1').drop_duplicates('Col3',keep='last')
Out[569]: 
   Col3 Col2  Col1
4     2    B   4.0
2     1    C   8.0
```

Or in case you have duplicate max value of mean

```
g1[g1.Col1==g1.groupby('Col3').Col1.transform('max')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following (I modified your code slightly,
to make it a bit shorter):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Col3','Col2'], as_index = False).mean()
```

When you print the result, for your input, you will get:

```
   Col3 Col2  Col1
0     1    A   6.0
1     1    B   3.5
2     1    C   8.0
3     2    A   3.5
4     2    B   4.0
5     2    C   2.0
```

Then run:

```
res = df2.iloc[df2.groupby('Col3').Col1.idxmax()]
```

When you print the result, you will get:

```
   Col3 Col2  Col1
2     1    C   8.0
4     2    B   4.0
```

As you can see:

- `idxmax` gives the index of the row with "maximal" element (for each
  group),
- this result you can use as the argument of `iloc`.